# Roll back to previous version of OneNote (Windows Desktop)

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote

It seems the new version of OneNote for Windows Desktop (1712) has broken search in password protected / encrypted sections. When I try to search a page (Ctrl-F) OneNote hangs while it searches the page without the use of the Windows Search Index. In contrast, non-password protected sections return instant results with no hanging.
I believe this is a bug introduced in the new version, so I would like to roll back to the previous version (1711).

How can I roll back / restore to the previous version of OneNote for Windows Desktop?

Comment: You would have to find an old installer.  That will be difficult since Microsoft doesn’t keep them around and the only installer is the current one

Comment: @Ramhound That's what I was thinking. Even worse - MS downloads an installer bootstrap type app that downloads the latest version from online. I was thinking maybe I could find an old copy of Office 2016 and re-install Office from scratch. However my Office is a download version, so I expect the full Office will have the latest version too. I would need to find a DVD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This OneNote 1712 encrypted section bug is discussed here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onenote-mso_win10-mso_o365b/onenote-2016-version-1712-ctrlf-search-slow-with/89bb01f6-4c18-42e5-a008-a7bb20d146e2

They provide a temporary solution to roll back OneNote by switching to the semi-annual channel following instructions here:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/odsupport/2017/05/10/how-to-switch-channels-for-office-2016-proplus/

Switching to the semi-annual channel rolled it back to an older version.

The steps are:

Open an administrative cmd prompt

Navigate to: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun

Run: OfficeC2RClient.exe  /changesetting Channel=Broad

Run: OfficeC2RClient.exe  /update user